# How to Insert function return into innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use JS to automatically calculate a persons age based on the current date, and then insert that result into a span using inner HTML but I keep getting NAN as the result. Any idea why?

I've tried placing the var x code in different places and also tried inserting `getAge` as the `innerHTML` but that just inserts the entire JS.

```js
var x = getAge();
document.getElementById("age-result").innerHTML = x;

function getAge(dateString) {
  var today = new Date();
  var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
  var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
  if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
    age--;
  }
  return age;
}

console.log('age: ' + getAge("1969/01/05"));
```

```html
<span id="age-result"></span>
```

What am I doing wrong?

`console.log` shows the correct result.

Comment: In `var x = getAge();` you don't pass `dateString` (like you do in `getAge("1969/01/05")`).

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges. `getAge()` is not equal to `getAge("1969/01/05")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var x = getAge("1969/01/05");
document.getElementById("age-result").innerHTML = x;

function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }

    return age;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="age-result"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

You forgot to pass a parameter to the `getAge` function.

Try this:

```js
var x = getAge("1969/01/05");
document.getElementById("age-result").innerHTML = x;

function getAge(dateString) {
  var today = new Date();
  var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
  var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
  if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
    age--;
  }

  return age;

}
```

```html
<span id="age-result"></span>
```